# ASPNET get ClientID in onchange event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, clientid

I use:

```
onchange="alert('<%= AbcControl.ClientID %>')"
```

but Unfortunately it will translate to:

```
onchange="alert('&lt;%= AbcControl.ClientID %>')"
```

May I know what is the best solution for this other than adding the onchange even during server side Page_Load even?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.id here

```
onchange="alert(this.id);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to see only Id (Client side generated id) of the `AbcControl`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="AbcControl" />
<input type="text" onchange='<%= "alert('"+ AbcControl.ClientID +"');" %>' />
```

OR

Try this, if you want to get the client side object of `AbcControl`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="AbcControl" />
<input type="text" onchange='<%= "alert("+ AbcControl.ClientID +");" %>' />
```